# npm start in create react app throws error(tries searching for react-scripts in weird place)

Tags: npm, create-react-app, npm-start, react-scripts

Other projects work just fine but this project for some reason throws this error:
[image]

The internal scripts from npm(version 8.19.1) appear to be trying to import react-scripts from my Desktop(???) instead of from node_modules.
Checking my node_module folder shows react-scripts correctly installed.

Comment: Your issue are the spaces and the ampersand characters is your path. The shell is interpreting it as different command 'jobs' and 'cv\soltinia'. These commands are not recognised, which is obvious.

Comment: isn't the path automatically put inside quotes to avoid this? This seems like bad handling on the part of the internal loader.

Comment: @W.S. thank you, that fixed it. Would you like to post your answer below so I can mark it as the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue are the spaces and the ampersand characters is your path. The shell is interpreting it as different commands 'jobs' and 'cv\soltinia'. These commands are not recognised, which is obvious.